# Doctrine multiple OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

In latest Doctrine on Symfony2 trying to work out multiple bidirectional relationship between two objects.

Person owner object has one postal Address and then multiple secondary Addresses in a collection, and I remove() the Person, I want all of it's addresses to also be deleted (but removing an address should not remove a Person), but I'm getting this error -

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM address WHERE id = ?' with
params {"1":"fb5e47de-2651-4069-b85e-8dbcbe8a6c4a"}:

[PDOException] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`db`.`address`, CONSTRAINT `FK_633704 C29C1004E`
FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`))
```

in

```
class Person
{

    /**
     * @var Address postalAddress
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $postalAddress;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection otherAddresses
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="person", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $otherAddresses;


}

class Address
{

    /**
     * @var Person person
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="postalAddress, otherAddresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $person;
}
```

I thought it might because the

```
inversedBy="postalAddress, otherAddresses"
```

I don't think multiple inversedBy is supported; then I also tried to change

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
```

to be nullable, but I still get the error.

This is obviously not about trivial Person/Address example but something more complex, but this was my best attempt at abstraction.

I'm sure I've missed something obvious. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think the issue might be that you're trying to say that a many to one is inversed by a OneToOne rather than a ManyToOne. Have you tried ` * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="otherAddresses") * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Person")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)` It might change the way doctrine handles the cascade, even though it does not change the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Broken Relational Definition

While what you are doing may make sense from a purely logical standpoint, it does not from a relational-data standpoint, and particularly makes no sense from Doctrine's perspective.

Doctrine is trying to maintain 3 different relationships:

- **Address** (owning-side) [bi-directional] $person `--Many:One-->` $otherAddresses **Person**
- **Address** (owning-side) [bi-directional] $person `--Many:One-->` $postalAddress **Person**
- **Person** (owning-side) [uni-directional] $postalAddress `--One:One-->` $id **Address**

You see the problem?

## Use relational standards for solving this problem.

The simple solution here is to use the VERY common design pattern of setting a primary for a collection. In essence, you only need one relationship:

- **Address** (owning-side) [bi-directional] $person `--Many:One-->` $otherAddresses **Person**

Then, add to address a property which defines that address to be the *primary*. Programattically handle this in the Person and Address entities:

```
Class Person
{
    . . .
    public function getPrimaryAddress() {
        if (null === $this->primaryAddress) {
            foreach($this->getOtherAddresses() as $address) {
                if ($address->isPrimary()) {
                    $this->primaryAddress = $address;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->primaryAddress;
    }

    // similar for the setter, update the old address as not primary if there is one, set the new one as primary.
}
```

## Use two different relationships, but *don't cross the streams*

If you keep the One-to-One relationship UNIDIRECTIONAL from Person to Address, the problem solves itself.

- **Address** (owning-side) [bi-directional] $person `--Many:One-->` $otherAddresses **Person**
- **Person** (owning-side) [uni-directional] $postalAddress `--One:One-->` **Address**

You're still going to have trouble here though, because Doctrine will complain if:
 - the main (**PostalAddress**) address doesn't have both sides for the *Many:One* defined. (so your "main" address will also have to be in the `$otherAddresses` collection). 
 - attempting to remove or cascade deletes and updates will result in those two relationships conflicting, "crossing streams" of doctrine's relational constraints, so you'll have to programatically handle those operations.

Comment: Note: the `Person::getPrimaryAddress` method could be made much cleaner with criteria.

Comment: oh man, I asked this 4 years ago. Now the solution is a bit more obvious to me but at the time I was not sure. Thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: Your question popped up as first in a Google search. While I figured you'd found the way around your problem by now, I wanted to help out the next lost coder who found their way here.